# Choice of analyzer for lucene.net full text search in books

Tags: vb.net, lucene, lucene.net, analyzer

I am using Lucene with vb.net. I want to make a full text search of some books which includes Arabic and English books. I am not very sure about the choice of analyzer I should use. It would be a great help if someone suggest me right analyzer from his/her experience. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to include stemming and other language-specific analysis rules, and can identify which language a document or query is in, you can use [ArabicAnalyzer](https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/d2/d94/class_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_analysis_1_1_a_r_1_1_arabic_analyzer.html) for your Arabic documents and queries, and [SnowballAnalyzer](https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/da/d40/class_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_analysis_1_1_snowball_1_1_snowball_analyzer.html) for English documents and queries (like: `new SnowballAnalyzer(myVersion, "English")`).

If you want to use non-language-specific analysis for all of them, you should generally stick with [StandardAnalyzer](https://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/df/d8b/class_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_analysis_1_1_standard_1_1_standard_analyzer.html).

Comment: Thanks, I am thinking StandardAnalyzer. Could you please elaborate some pros and cons of it. Is it work with special characters?